# Awk command always adding string in the begining

Tags: awk, sed, gawk

Why does the below statement adds zeros the begining instead of end. 'm trying this on a Cloudera-CentOS Virtual machine. Thanks.

```
head -n 20 ratings.csv |  awk '{print $0"000"}'
000rId,movieId,rating,timestamp
000,3.5,1112486027
0009,3.5,1112484676
0002,3.5,1112484819
0007,3.5,1112484727
0000,3.5,1112484580
00012,3.5,1094785740
00051,4.0,1094785734
00023,4.0,1112485573
00053,4.0,1112484940
00060,4.0,1112484826
00093,4.0,1112484703
00096,4.0,1112484767
00018,4.0,1112484798
00037,3.5,1094785709
00067,3.5,1112485980
00041,4.0,1112484603
00089,3.5,1112485557
00093,3.5,1112484661
00053,3.0,1094785691
```

Comment: Maybe the file contains Windows-style line endings with carriage returns?

Answer (score 0):

Your file has CRLF type of line endings. Change your awk code to:

`awk 'sub(/\r/,""); print $0"000"}'`

`sub` will remove the CR or \r from the records.